# Unable to write an if-else statement as an AMPL constraint

Tags: matlab, if-statement, optimization, controller, ampl

I am trying to write a constraint in AMPL which looks like as following in MATLAB:

```
if ((T[t+1, 1] <= T[t, 1]) and (T[t+1, 1] <= T_set - 1))
    status[t+1] = 0;
elseif ((T[t+1, 1] > T[t, 1]) and (T[t+1, 1] >= T_set + 2))
    status[t+1] = 1;
else
    status[t+1] = status[t];
end
```

I made following attempt in AMPL with no success:

```
subject to status01 {t in 1..duration}: ind01[t] = if (T[t+1, 1] <= T[t, 1]) then 1;
subject to status02 {t in 1..duration}: ind02[t] = if (T[t+1, 1] <= T_set - 1) then 1;
subject to status0 {t in 1..duration}: Status[t+1] = if (ind01[t] + ind02[t] == 2) then 0;
subject to status03 {t in 1..duration}: ind0[t] = if (ind01[t] + ind02[t] <> 2) then 1;

subject to status11 {t in 1..duration}: ind11[t] = if (T[t+1, 1] >= T[t, 1]) then 1;
subject to status12 {t in 1..duration}: ind12[t] = if (T[t+1, 1] >= T_set + 2) then 1;
subject to status1 {t in 1..duration}: Status[t+1] = if (ind11[t] + ind12[t] == 2) then 1;
subject to status13 {t in 1..duration}: ind1[t] = if (ind11[t] + ind12[t] <> 2) then 1;

subject to status2 {t in 1..duration}: Status[t+1] = Status[t] * ind0[t] * ind1[t];
```

The code is unable to set the value of any of the indicator i.e. `ind01`, `ind02`, etc.

Please help where am I doing incorrectly.